# Insert auto-number from newly inserted row in Access with Coldfusion

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, insert

I have a few tables: a medError table, an option table, and a selected_options table.

When somebody submits the relevant form, I have an insert which inserts all the info from the form to the medError table. However, on this form, there is a section of dynamic checkboxes based on the items in the option table. The selected_options table holds the ID of the row in the medError table along with selected options based on the IDs in the option table.

How would I take the ID # from the newly inserted row in the medError table and insert it into the selected_options table?

I'm using Coldfusion and Access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See options #2 or #3 (@@IDENTITY -or- UUID column) for methods that should work with MS Access. 
http://mysecretbase.com/get_the_last_id.cfm

If you were using an enterprise database like MS SQL or MySQL you could use [cfquery's result attribute](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html). But IIRC, it is not supported for MS Access. One of the many reasons to upgrade..

Comment: Thanks! And yeah, we are going to upgrade to MySQL at some point. Just seems like whenever there will be time, something else is more important..

Comment: Yes, switching databases is not a small task. But it is worth it, when you finally get around to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go with the mySQL conversion. This [Access to mySQL converter](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) may help. Depending on your SQL may less painful than you imagine.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! This will definitely make the transition easier.